# Adding html to a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html table like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="700">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="dark" colspan="2">
            Customer Details
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
               Customer Contact Name
       </td>
       <td>
           <input name="tbname" type="text" id="tbname" class="widetb">
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add Some text  at the start of the table so it's the first td in the table, how can I do this using jquery? I really don't have clue where to start.

I have to do it this way as I don't have access to change this via the html.

Comment: have you searched? Their are lot of examples on how to insert text of html using jquery. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner :

```
   $('td.dark').text('Enter your text here!'); // the class is present in your HTML
```

This will search for  the `td` with class `dark` which represents the first td and it will insert the text.

In case you have multiple tables:

```
$('td.dark').eq(0).text('Enter your text here!'); 

// here 0 represents the position of the table  minus 1 , you want to change the text
```

Comment: They also mentioned in comment, they had "other tables", so `.dark` may exist on those too.

Comment: What i infer from the OP comment is, that piece of code was matching the first td without class. So it might have matched in other tables also. In case the OP has same class in those too. Then we need the table position. then can define  $('td.dark').eq(1).text('Enter your text here!');

Comment: eq(0) not eq(1) as arrays are zero based :-)

Answer (score 1):

As example, so:

```
$('td', 'table').first().text('hello!');
```

Comment: Yes, it's more efficient this kind of selector. It means "all td of all tables". Looking to my example `$('td', 'table').first()`, it means "the first td of all tds of all tables".
As point, you can use descendant selectors inside first parameter `$('tr > td', 'table')`

Comment: This looks close but it's interfering with other tables on my page

Comment: Is it really more efficient than say $('table:first td').first() or $('table:first td:first')?

Comment: The user has .dark as the class for the first td, why shouldn't we target that :P  $('td.dark').text('Enter your text here!'); :P

Comment: @mohamedrias because the first td of a table is always the first td, having class or not. Anyway, I also think it is ok.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I meant the selection constructor, putting first the descendand, then the parent `$('p', 'div')`. I thougt you asked for that :)

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with that constructor, but having looked into it I will personally have to avoid it (it reads backwards to me, compared to other selectors).

Answer (score 1):

You could try a google search next time.

The jquery method `find` finds the set of elements in a parent matching a selector, and `eq` selects a certain element from the set (with element 1 being referenced by 0 as in arrays). Therefore, you can use the following if you only have one table in your entire document:

```
$("table") // select all tables
    .eq(0) // select the one you want (the only one)
    .find("td") // select all td's
    .eq(0) // select the first one (the one you want)
    .html("insert new content here"); // set the td's inner html
```

If you have multiple tables, it's tricky. You will need the index of your table relative to other tables. For example, if you have

```
<table>...</table>
...
<table>...</table>
...
<table>table you are targeting</table>
.......
```

Then the index of your table would be `2` because it is the third table in the document, and indices start at 0. If you have an index, you can use

```
var table_index=// set this to the index
$("table") // select all tables
    .eq(table_index) // select the one you want (with the index)
    .find("td") // select all td's
    .eq(0) // select the first one (the one you want)
    .html("insert new content here"); // set the td's inner html
```

Comment: They did mention they "can't change the HTML", so presumably can't add the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Give ID to that First td as your code looks like

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="700">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td id="firsttd" class="dark" colspan="2">
               Customer Details
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               Customer Contact Name
           </td>
           <td>
               <input name="tbname" type="text" id="tbname" class="widetb">
           </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#firsttd').text("Your title here");
</script>
```

Comment: Downvoted for bad capitalization, bad grammar, use of 'ur,' and not closing your first script tag

Comment: They also did mention they "can't change the HTML".

Comment: I will remove my downvote but in the future make sure to maintain a professional attitude on Stack Exchange, and make sure to write correct code.

Comment: Sure i will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you give your table an id, then you can do something similar to:

```
$('#id >tbody').prepend('<tr><td>A shiny new row<td></tr>');
```

Comment: They did mention they "can't change the HTML", so presumably can't add the ID.

Comment: I don't have access to change the html, I'm afraid so I can't add an id.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Fair comment - just have to assume only one table on the page and change the selector to 'tbody'

Comment: `$('tbody').first().prepend(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the HTML at all and if you have multiple tables then this will work:

```
var newTR = $( "<tr id='newRow'/>" );
var newTRcontent = "<td colspan=1>Your New Text Here</td>";
$("table:nth-of-type(2) tbody tr").first().before(newTR);
$("#newRow").html(newTRcontent);
```

I made an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7XNt2/1/)

Basically it about using the proper JQuery selector so `$(table:nth-of-type(2)` will select the second table. Then you can use the code I have above or maybe even better yet here is a one-liner:

```
$("table:nth-of-type(2) tbody tr").first().before("<tr><td>Your New Text Here</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Of course this answer assumes you want to actually add a new row which is how I interpreted your question.